# How to point React component with this in a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, this, react-component

I am trying to create a filler gauge with D3.js and React integrated. First of all, please take a look at my code below:

```
componentDidMount() {
  renderOuterGauge();
  renderInnerGauge();
}

componentDidUpdate() {
  renderOuterGauge();
}

renderInnerGauge = () => {
  const innerGauge = this.svg.append('path')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(60,100)')
    .attr('stroke', 'transparent')
    .attr('d', 'M0,0 l440,-60 v100 h-440 v-40')
    .on('click', function(d) {
      const x = d3.mouse(this)[0];
      const yUP = x / (440 / -60);
      const score = x / 4.38;
      console.log(score);
      this.setState({
        score: score
      })
      d3.event.this.setAttribute('d', `M0,0 l${x},${yUP} v${yUP+40} h${-x} v-40`);
      d3.event.this.setAttribute('fill', 'forestgreen');
    })
}
```

As shown above, I'm trying to fill inner gauges dynamically using `this.setState` method, but since the method call is in a closure, I cannot use `setState` on `this`.

Usually I can fix this with using arrow function definition, however as far as I know, in order to get `x` and `y` value using `d3.mouse(this)` in the gauge, I cannot use arrow function. For such cases, is there a way to point `this` as the react component AND use the mouse method in the same function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, when you dive into certain Javascript functions, the meaning of `this` can change.  However, the function maintains access to the variables that are scoped above it.  So you can create an interim variable that holds the value of `this` and then reference it from *inside* your function like so:

```
renderInnerGauge = () => {
    const self = this;
    const innerGuage = this.svg.doAllTheThings('foo').on('click', function(d) {
        console.log('self', self); // this is the value of the "outer" this 
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this? Just point `this` to a variable before going into the closure.

```
renderInnerGauge = () => {

    const self = this

    const innerGauge = this.svg.append('path')
            .attr('transform','translate(60,100)')
            .attr('stroke','transparent')
            .attr('d','M0,0 l440,-60 v100 h-440 v-40')
            .on('click', function(d){
                const x = d3.mouse(this)[0];
                const yUP = x/(440/-60);
                const score = x/4.38;
                console.log(score);

                // Changed to 'self'
                self.setState({
                    score: score
                })
                d3.event.this.setAttribute('d',`M0,0 l${x},${yUP} v${yUP+40} h${-x} v-40`);
                d3.event.this.setAttribute('fill','forestgreen');
            }) 

    }
```